# dynamic file extensions htaccess redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I have to redirect current PHP dynamic pages:

http://www.sample.com/page/2/?wpec_spao=include-inserting-tool

So I want everything that has: "http://www.sample.com/page/2/?wpec_spao=" to be redirected regardless of remaining part of the link (that remaining part is dynamically generated) to:

http://www.sample.com/site-moved-page/

Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/page/2/\?wpec_spao= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sample.com/site-moved-page/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Now I get redirection like this: `http://www.sample.com/?wpec_spao=include-inserting-tool`